# Extract a number between 2 strings in Teradata

Tags: teradata, strtok, regexp-substr

I need help extracting 49 from this string: "7 DAYS LATE  49 UNDERUSE" in Teradata, I keep on messing up with STRTOK or regexp_substr. Thanks

Comment: Cann you show some more example data covering your rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract a number between two strings.  Here's one way:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
  '7 DAYS LATE 49 UNDERUSE' -- source string
  '.*\w*\s+(\d+)\w*\s+.*', -- regexp pattern
  1, 1, 'i' -- additional options (start position, match #, case sensitivity)
)
```

This will give you the first matching number between two strings that precede and follow whitespace.

[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/aohu2GV5DgPH0R5jQKr2HQ)
[SQL Fiddle (Postgres)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/49829)

Answer (score 0):

---

```
select strtok('7 DAYS LATE 49 UNDERUSE',' ',4);
```